# RIGHT JOIN with composite primary key not retrieving all data

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key, right-join

I have a MySQL db to store some equipment IP address, vendors and service status with the following structure (simplified for illustration):

- Table **equipment** (id, ipaddress) as primary key

> ```
> id    ipaddress       name
> 1234  10.20.30.40     NY Router
> 1234  10.31.41.51     DC Router
> 2222  10.255.99.22    CA Router
> ```

- Table **vendor**

> ```
>   id      name    
>   1       Cisco
>   2       Juniper
>   3       Huawei
> ```

- Table **equipment_vendor**

> ```
> id    equipment_id    equipment_ipaddress     vendor_id
> 1     1234            10.20.30.40             1
> 2     1234            10.31.41.51             1
> 3     2222            10.255.99.22            2
> 4     2222            10.255.99.20            2
> ```

Notes:

1) About equipment table, in the past pk was only the id, but I had to include ipaddress because I figured out different equipment with the same id but different ip address.

2) I now that vendor could be a column of equipment instead of an associative table. It's only for demonstrative purpose.

Issue:
As shown above, for some unknown reason, there are old records that exists in the equipment_vendor table but there is no related record in the equipment table anymore (as in record id=4 above, there's no 2222-10.255.99.20 in the equipment table).
Then I need to retrieve all equipments in the same situation. I did:

```
SELECT * FROM equipment AS a
RIGHT JOIN equipment_vendor AS b ON a.id = b.equipment_id AND a.ipaddress = b.equipment_ipaddress
```

This shows me only the "existent" equipment, but I need just the opposite, I need the inexistent ones. I thought RIGHT JOIN function was intended to do that, to get all from the right table even if there is no associated record in the left one. Am I wrong?
I tried every type of join and tried to invert the sequence (equipment_vendor join equipment).

I hope you can help me with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

> NOT IN

```
SELECT ev.equipment_id, ev.equipment_ipaddress FROM equipment_vendor ev WHERE ev.equipment_ipaddress NOT IN (SELECT eq.ipaddress FROM equipment eq);
```

Comment: :D I think I'm rusty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT * 
FROM equipment_vendor ev 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM equipment eq 
                 WHERE eq.id = ev.equipment_id
                 AND eq.ipaddress = ev.equipment_ipaddress)
```